# Navbar is not honoring class="row"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Apache Flask and bootstrap to build a simple website. The site must have a side navbar, and must display either home page or test page upon clicking the links for 'home' and 'test'. In order to do this, I need help in setting up the base template correctly. My unsuccessful attempt is below:

Code for base template

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link     href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>
            {% block title %} {% endblock %}
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "row">
            <div class="col-mid-6" >
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/test">test page</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-mid-6"
                {% block content %} {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code for index.html that inherits the template:

```
{% extends "base_test.html" %}
{% block title %} Home page {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1> We are now in home page </h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Flask driver code:

```
#Template folder contains base_test.html
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")
    # return "Hi How are you?"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: You use `col-mid-6` instead of `col-md-6` as the class for the columns. After the adjustment it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap row and column you need either container or container-fluid as a wrapper class.And as mestion by @Detlef there is typo error insted of mid it would be md.

```
<div class="conatiner">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
   <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```